# If $A$ be positive semidefinite then $[a_{i j} /(i + j )]$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = [ai j ] \in M_{n*n}$ is positive semidefinite.

Why does the matrix $[a_{i j} /(i + j )]$ is
also positive semidefinite?

Comment: Combine [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215719/is-this-matrix-positive-semi-definite) with [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711918/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-hadamard-product-of-two-positive-definite-matric/).