# $\sum\limits_{j,k} {{a_{jk}}} {\bar u_j}{u_k}\mathop = \limits^? \int_0^1 | \sum\limits_j {{u_j}} {x^j}{|^2}x{\mkern 1mu} dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $U\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $a_{jk}=\int_0^1 x^{j+k-1}\,dx$

Is this true that

$\sum_{j,k} a_{jk}\bar u_ju_k=\int_0^1\Bigl|\sum_j u_jx^j\Bigr|^2x\,dx$

Comment: Since your question clearly is concerned with [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215719/is-this-matrix-positive-semi-definite/215731), it would have been good to reference that answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true because
$$
\left|
\sum_{j=1}^nu_jx^j
\right|^2
=
\overline{
\left(
\sum_{j=1}^nu_jx^j
\right)}
\left(
\sum_{j=1}^nu_jx^j
\right)
=
\left(
\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{u}_jx^j
\right)
\left(
\sum_{j=1}^nu_jx^j
\right)
=
\sum_{j=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^n
\bar{u}_j u_k x^{j+k}
$$
so
$$
\int_0^1\left|
\sum_{j=1}^nu_jx^j
\right|^2x\,\mathrm{d}x
=
\sum_{j=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^n
\bar{u}_j u_k \int_0^1x^{j+k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$

Comment: By your proof, then this proof (math.stackexchange.com/questions/215719/…) is not true?

Comment: @H.S You might want to ask the author for more details.

Comment: It was just a typo in my proof. Fixed now.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks I thought I saw this formula somewhere :)